# IE9 and IE10 dictionaries rendering

Tags: angularjs, dictionary, internet-explorer-9, internet-explorer-10

I'm having problem with rendering dictionaries values in ie9 and ie10. What I'm doing is rendering `<select>` item by iterating over dictionary:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-condensed">
  <tr data-ng-repeat="(rightKey, value) in rightValuesLinksForSelectedType">
    <td><label>{{rightNames[rightKey]}}</label></td>
    <td>
      <select data-ng-model="rightsSelected[rightKey]" class="form-control">
        <option data-ng-repeat="(wordKey, wordValue) in value"
          data-ng-selected="wordValue" value="{{wordKey}}">
            {{rightValues[wordKey]}}
        </option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The dictionaries are provided by api. All works under firefox/chrome/ie11 but fails in ie9 and ie10. What I see after page is rendered is that some of the values in `<option>` are not rendered (they look like in the code - `{{rightValues[wordKey]}}`, and some of them are rendered correctly. Dictionaries are provided by api, I can't do anything about how they look. The 'value' in the first ng-repeat is another dictionary I iterate over in the second ng-repeat. As for `data-ng-selected="wordValue"` - wordValue is either 'true' or 'false'. Note that not all of the `<select>` values are incorrect and after I expand the select I see correctly rendered text. Any clue?